# Wordpress: figuring out which hook called a function

Tags: wordpress, hook

I'm trying to figure out if the same function is hooked onto multiple actions, can I figure out which action calls it?

I'd like to send out an API call when a user is created and deleted; the functionality in both cases is the same except one data point would be different based on if its created or deleted. It doesn't feel right making two identical functions with only one difference, but I'm not sure how else I can do it.

Advice?

Answer (score 8):

That's the function [`current_filter()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_filter):

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'common_action' );
add_action( 'admin_init', 'common_action' );

function common_action()
{
    switch( current_filter() )
    {
        case 'plugins_loaded':
            // do_something( 'Plugins loaded' );
        break;
        case 'admin_init':
            // do_another_thing( 'Admin init' );
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great one, mate, I would totally upvote you if I could!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question - when running a function, which action was triggering it?  The key is `$wp_current_filter`.

Example:

```
//  Both of these will call the same function
do_action('wp', 'my_function');
do_action('init', 'my_function');

function my_function() {
    // How do I know if this was 'init', 'wp', or some other hook?
    // Global in the WordPress variable $wp_filter
    global $wp_current_filter;
    if ($wp_current_filter == 'wp' || in_array('wp', $wp_current_filter)) {
        // Do my "wp" based stuff....
    }
    if ($wp_current_filter == 'init' || in_array('init', $wp_current_filter)) {
        // Do my "init" based stuff....
    }
}
```

**Note:** This is a lousy use-case example, but it conveys the principles!